# Select record field ignoring duplicate (indexed table)

Tags: sql, select, duplicates, firebird

I have an indexed table "Quotes" (PK, QUOTE, AUTHOR, URL, CATEGORY):

For example:

```
 PK    QUOTE               AUTHOR     URL                                             CATEGORY
 *********************************************************************************************
 1     SOME QUOTE TEXT     DARWIN     https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Darwin    NATURE
 2     SOME OTHER QUOTE    NEWTON     https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Newton      SOCIETY
 3     ANOTHER QUOTE TEXT  MANDELA    https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelson_Mandela    VARIOUS
 4     SOME QUOTE TEXT     DARWIN     https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Darwin    RELIGION
 5     BLA BLA BLA BLA     NEWTON     https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Newton      SOCIETY
```

In a new query I want to select only fields (NAME and URL) but ignoring duplicates records.

The table already has a primary key index. The goal is to select authors from QUOTES table and to avoid creating a duplicate author for the user if this one already exists.

For my example above, my query should return only:

```
 AUTHOR     URL
 **********************************************************
 DARWIN     https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Darwin
 NEWTON     https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Newton
 MANDELA    https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelson_Mandela
```

Ignoring the two duplicates rows for (NEWTON and DARWIN).

Comment: What exactly is your goal here? Why do you also need to select PK (and why that specific value?), or do you just need unique AUTHOR + URL combinations? What if an author occurs with different URLs? Which Firebird version do you use?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Sorry that was an error, i do not want Primary key only Name and URL

Comment: you would still better create non-unique indices on `Author` and `URL` to help Firebird with filtering duplicates. Additionally, i would think if there can be rows with the same value of `Author` yet different values of `URL` or vice versa? if not, then perhaps you can "normalize" your DB further, extracting Author+URL into a dictionary table, where Author WOULD be a PK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use [`DISTINCT`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-dml-select-column-list):

```sql
select distinct AUTHOR, URL
from "Quotes"
```

This will output each combination of `AUTHOR` and `URL` once (assuming they are not blob types).